# Identify web app user with using windows domain name

Tags: security, tomcat, web-applications, windows-authentication

I have a GWT webapp running on tomcat 7 on RedHat. All clients reside within intranet and use IE7 from XP machines to access the webapp.

The new requirement is to setup per user log. If user claims he did something wrong because of webapp, the admin should be able to check webapp responses for that request. Another requirement(a very nice to have feature) is to avoid login/password screen and use domain username instead.

I think I can ask my admin to setup Integrated Windows Authentication for Tomcat http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2011/06/22/windows-authentication-apache-tomcat. Once IWA is implemented on Tomcat I expect I will be able to access username with HTTPServletRequest.getRemoteUser() from my webapp.

1. Am I right in my assumption?
2. Is there a simpler way than that?

Answer (score 0):

The integration of a Java container such as Tomcat with a Windows Domain through IWA, SPNEGO, Kerberos etc. can be a very complicated task and the Tomcat instructions that you point to may or may not work the first time and may also require changes to the way your Windows environment is configured.

Once that integration is working, your web application will need to specify auth constraints in web.xml to protect part or whole of the webapp.  Although it may not prompt for user id if the Windows authentication set up is working seamlessly, it is necessary for the configuration to be there before getRemoteUser will return anything inside your application.